# Widgets panel not displaying in the Theme Customizer

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I am using the Theme Customizer to let users customize how their website looks.

I noticed on the Twenty Fifteen theme there is a panel for Widgets. I have seen this on quite a few other themes too, and the code for the panel has not been added to `customizer.php` (as far as I can tell)

On my theme, I have a few sidebars on the homepage. You can customize the widgets through `Appearance > Widgets` menus, however the Widgets panel in the customizer is not displaying.

How can I get it to show in the customizer so the user does not have to keep switching out to change the widgets?

My code for registering the sidebar:

```
function widgets_init_mysite() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'mytheme' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'widgets_init_mysite' );
```

I add the sidebar to the page using `dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )`

It is definitely displayed because I added widgets through `Appearance > Widgets` and I can see them in the customizer.

**Note:** One interesting thing I did find. I registered 5 Sidebars, with IDs of `sidebar-1`, `sidebar-2` etc. In Firefix, I went to the theme customizer and Inspect Element. I found the Widgets panel existed, but had `display: none`. What is more interesting, in the `ul` sub-navigation, there were 5 `li` elements with the class `section-sidebar-widgets-sidebar-1` (the last number changed for all the sidebars).

I checked the other sections I had made, and the class always started with `section-`, and then the section ID. I tried changing the panel of the sidebars to my panel like so:

`$wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-1' )->panel = 'my-panel';`

But nothing happened. This is weird because I know pretty much definitely know the names of the Sidebar Sections, but changing their panel does nothing...

Comment: You are asking about your code without showing it. How do you expect people to know what you are doing wrong?

Comment: The only thing I can do is post all the code in the `customizer.php` file, and I am not comfortable doing that. I just want to know if there is some Wordpress feature that lets you enable that panel, not for my code to be debugged.

Comment: No, the bug is in your code.

Comment: No, I removed all the code from the `customizer.php` and the panel still did not show.

Comment: Could you post the code you have for adding the widget areas?

Comment: I didn't say the bug is in that file, but since it doesn't seem like you want an answer I will stop here.

Comment: @Arcath I have posted the code for registering the sidebars, is that what you wanted?

Comment: @MarkKaplun What do you want me to do then? Post all the code in every file? Sorry but you are not very clear in asking what you want from me.

Comment: You say the Widgets panel had `display: none`... where was that coming from? Was it an inline style or coming from one of your stylesheets?

Comment: It was an inline style, on the element itself. I assume WP adds all the panels to the customizer, and has a PHP / JS script to hide panel that should not be shown. It was not from on of my stylesheets (though I don't think you can add a stylesheet to affect the theme customizer itself)

Comment: @megmorsie I assume there is no setting type for a Sidebar? What I aim to achieve is to move the Widget areas out of the widgets panel and into panels I create for different things, so under the homepage panel, there may be a section for widgets. In that section, the user can control the widgets for different sidebar, and move them around, change their content, etc.

Comment: did u place dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) at the top of the loop?

Comment: What do you mean "at the top of the loop"? I just added it to the body of `index.php`

Answer (score 2):

I see you're talking about the `dynamic_sidebar` function but I don't see you mention the sidebar file (eg. `sidebar.php` or `sidebar-single.php`).

There are basically 3 steps I follow to display sidebar widgets and they're always visible in customizer. If yours is not showing up, you probably may have missed something.

**1. The register part in functions.php**

---

```
$args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'mytheme' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>'
);
register_sidebar( $args );
```

**2. The function call in a sidebar file (eg. `sidebar.php` or `sidebar-single.php`)**

---

```
<?php
// Dynamic Sidebar
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1') ) :
    // Sidebar fallback content
    get_sidebar();
endif;
// End Dynamic Sidebar Single posts
?>
```

**3. Call the sidebar in the post/page template**

---

`<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` or `<?php get_sidebar('single'); ?>` for `sidebar-single.php`

I would advise you to re-check your code to make sure you haven't left anything out. All the best!

Comment: No, I was not using `sidebar.php`, because I had multiple sidebars. I was registering them in `functions.php` and calling them directly in `index.php` via `dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-id')`. I had created `sidebar.php` but it was completely blank. I tried using `sidebar.php` but it still did not show the Widgets panel, even after I copy + pasted your code

Comment: Well, in that case there must be something else that you're overlooking.  I'd advise you to update WordPress to the latest version and disable all plugins to narrow down the search, there may be a conflict somewhere. And If possible, get the theme on Github or Bitbucket repo so everyone else can have a look at the code. You'll probably get a solution faster.

Comment: I am on the latest version (4.4), with no plugins. Also, sorry, I cannot upload my theme files to GitHub for the public for various reasons (which is why I posted all the relevant code).

Comment: @Druzion I'm afraid I can't help you further. I did my best but It's difficult to propose solution to a problem I can't replicate. :(

Comment: Note after all of this time: as mentioned in the above answer, the register sidebar code (#1) needs to be in the functions.php file. It should not be in a separate customizer file (if you have one) - even if you include the customizer file in your functions.php. Spent many hours figuring that out (even after reading this several times). Thanks. (voted up)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not displaying the sidebar when the costumizer is active which prevents the costumizer from detecting its existence on the page.

The costumizer detects the sidebar by hooking on various sidebar related hooks that are supposed to be triggered when the page is generated. If for some reason your sidebar display code do not trigger the hooks the costumizer will not know it is there even if the actual content is being displayed. This can happen for example if you cache your sidebar and instead of calling `dynamic_display` you just output the sidebar.

Comment: The sidebar is displayed - I added widgets through it from `Appearance > Widgets`, and I can see them on the page. Is the customizer maybe not detecting them? I have added it to the page using `dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )`

Comment: I expanded a little

Comment: Okay thanks. As I said earlier, I display my sidebar using `dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )`. What do I need to do differently to get the customizer to detect it?